# Hibernate mapping customization to support List

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

We want to introduce Hibernate into a legacy project and run into a problem. We have two pojos :

```
public class Child {

    private String name;
    private List<Parent> parents;

}
```

and

```
public class Parent {

    private String name;
    private String type;

    public Parent(String name, String type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

The child table looks like this :

```
|name|mother|father|...
|Joe|Anne|George|...
```

The name field can be easily mapped, but the mother and father should be first converted into a Person object then added to the parents list.

To make things worse we can't change the POJOs as they are coming from a 3rd party library, so our only option is to use mapping xml files.

Obviously the database isn't normalized, but we cannot change that either.

I was thinking to use JPA 2.1 style [@Converter](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Basic_Attributes#Converters_.28JPA_2.1.29) but that one only converts a single field into a single field, just different type, and I cannot find support for it in xml. Is there any other way?

Comment: I believe you shall map two other objects using HBM, and then convert them on the fly to your objects. By the way how can you recognize which person is father and which is mother?

Comment: thanks, I will try to make that work. By the way the field "String type" controls whether it is a mother or father